# Removing a calendar in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

In Outlook 2007, I currently have a personal folder with two calendars in it. I am trying to delete one of the empty calendars.

However, I do not get the option to delete the calendar when I right click on it. They are within the same data file so I can't get around the problem by deleting the data file. I have somehow managed to end up with all the calendar items I want in one calendar called `'calendar1'` and an empty calendar called `'calendar'`. The one I want to delete (`'calendar'`) also won't let me change the name, etc.

How can I end up with just one calendar called `'calendar'` with all my calendar stuff within?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/merge-items-from-multiple-calendars-HA102075248.aspx

Simply open Calendar1, export to a file, open Calendar, import from a file, and remove Calendar1.